# Red underline that I cant figure out how to fix

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm brand new to iPhone programming. I've tried some tutorials and such and now I'm trying to do a simple project to get my feet wet. And of course I have having issues getting it to do what I want. I started it by using a Navigation project. I didn't want the UITableView though I just want normal buttons that lead to the next page. Although when I tried to get rid of the UITableView I think I did it wrong so now it isn't working when I am setting up the next view.

Here is the .h (the red underline is under the MPHViewController in both places) Oh and what it wants to do is make both those UIViewController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MPHViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    MPHViewController *mphViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) MPHViewController *mphViewController;
@end
```

I'm thinking where I mainly messed up was in the .m (I think) I took out all the code that had to do with the UITableView and simply put this in (wasn't sure what else should be placed there).

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControl:(UIView *)view 
{

}
```

Sorry for being a pain I just don't know any better way of learning how to do this other then just trial and error.

Comment: Did you import "`MPHViewController.h`" into your Xcode project?

Comment: What does the error say in xcode? Or when you try to compile?

Comment: @chown I just added that above that code snippet. It tries to replace it with UIViewController

Comment: @esqew It is added in right there on the RootViewController as an import. Was I supposed to import it somewhere else other than the MPHViewController.m?

Comment: No, I said your *Xcode Project*. Did you do a `File` > `Import`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be able to find the definition for your custom class.

In xcode under the project setting -> build phases, make sure the `MPHViewController.m` is included in the list of source files to be compiled.

---

Also, make sure in your `MPHViewController.h` that your subclassing UIViewController properly:

```
@interface MPHViewController : UIViewController
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm just going to check it as you solving it. XCode is just way to confusing to me. Know any other ways I could build my android apps into iPhone that isn't as much of a pain?

Comment: Use one of the templates that xcode provides when you create a new project.  Or, just google for something like "xcode universal" and you should get a bunch of tutorials for creating a project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you synthesize it in the .m

```
@synthesize mphViewController;
```

Comment: This would only give a warning, not a "red underline" error. I believe.

Comment: @TommyG It is giving me a error on that as well because it still hasnt solved the error on that code on the RootViewController.h

Comment: @steven - you will need to provide more info i think

Comment: btw - i am not sure why you are declaring your next view as an ivar. not sure it's necessary in your case.

Comment: @TommyG Ya it was a mix of me using Navigation application project and eliminating the TableView stuff and trying to replace it with a UIView and following a tutorial that makes a button lead to the next page. So I'm sure I made plenty of mistakes between the 2.